# Linq To Entities Internal Conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I must to execute this expression:

```
var CAP = modelCap.AZCPC00F.Where(x => x.CPCVER == CPCVER && x.CPCNAR == CPCNAR && x.CPCCAP == CPCCAP)
                               .Where(x => XXXXKG == 0 ? true : Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble(x.CPCLKG)) < XXXXKG)
                               .Where(x => XXXXMC == 0 ? true : Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble(x.CPCLMC)) < XXXXMC)
                               .Where(x => XXXXFD == "N" ? true : x.CPCZFD == XXXXFD).FirstOrDefault();
```

When I try to execute this I have an exception on the internal conversion of x.CPCLKG. The exception is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'int64' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I know that the problem is in the conversion but how can i use this function?

An example of x.CPCLKG is 9.9999 and is an nChar character type.

Thanks to all

Comment: Can you try using double.Parse and long.Parse rather than Convert.ToInt64 and Convert.ToDouble ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the logic that is not supported in Linq To Entities done in an in-memory query. We can do this by calling ToList() on the parts of the query that are supported. This will execute those parts, and return the results as a list. We can then execute whatever Linq supports on that list, in memory.

```
var CAP = modelCap.AZCPC00F.Where(x => x.CPCVER == CPCVER && x.CPCNAR == CPCNAR && x.CPCCAP == CPCCAP)
                           .Where(x => XXXXFD == "N" ? true : x.CPCZFD == XXXXFD)
                           .ToList();

var CAP2 = CAP.Where(x => XXXXKG == 0 ? true : Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble(x.CPCLKG)) < XXXXKG)
              .Where(x => XXXXMC == 0 ? true : Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDouble(x.CPCLMC)) < XXXXMC).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: @Ale I forgot to add ToList() to the first query. Without that, your query and mine had the same result. ToList() execute that query and bring in the List to memory, and the second query will then work in-memory.